# Is it possible to read files stored on a computer?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I want to access a file in computer(c:\test.bin) and to read it as byte array .Is it possible in Windows phone .

Thanks and Regards

vaysage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access a file via any standard file I/O apis.

You can run a web server on that computer, make the file available via http and include the appropriate client access policy file in the web site.  You can then download the file via `WebClient` using `OpenReadAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to upload something as a project asset, then you should force it to be a "content" from the properties panel and then access it using :

```
Uri uriMyFile = new Uri("test.bin",UriKind.relative);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader((Application.GetResourcesStream(
uriMyFile)).Stream);
```

Comment: how does this relate to the question of reading files from a connected PC?

Comment: well it doesn't, unless you parcel the file off to the device, and access it there !!! Either do it over the internet or pass it along as an asset. only 2 routes!!